# How to animate only a background of 2 in CSS3?

Tags: html, css

Hy everyone, I have this **CSS style**:

```
body { 
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
    background:#fff;
    background-image: url(bg.png), url(clouds.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin:0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes float {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 1200px 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1024px) {
    body {
      -webkit-animation-name: float;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -moz-animation-name: float;
        -moz-animation-duration: 60s;
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
}
```

This code animate **bg.png** image. But I want to animate **clouds.png** image. 
What can I do to animate **clouds.png** and not **bg.png**? :)

Comment: Is it an option to put the second background in an absolute div, and animate that div?

Comment: I can not because I have many pages and that would mean to open each page to change the body tag. Anything else? Thx!

Comment: You could do it with JavaScript, if that's an option.

Comment: Is an option, may be added tag in head. But how do it performs with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changed this:** `background-image: url(bg.png), url(clouds.png);`

**In this:** `background-image: url(clouds.png), url(bg.png);`